# Java, reference to an object of a class?

Tags: java

If I wanted to take the class StoreInventory and its attributes and use those attributes in a new class how do I include the StoreInventory in my new class Snacks?

Comment: As this is homework, I feel as if this topic should had been previously discussed in your text-book of some sort. I would advise you to review and see if you can figure it out, try out some code and if it doesn't work respond back with any problems you come across.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:homework] tag since it has been deprecated. Please click the tag link to see that it has been marked obsolete and why.

Answer (score 1):

You state:

> If I wanted to take the class StoreInventory and its attributes and use those attributes in a new class how do I include the StoreInventory in my new class Snacks?

Your logic doesn't smell right to me. Wouldn't it be the other way around -- StoreInventory should hold Snack objects and not be Snack objects holding StoreInventory objects?

Note that whatever you do, and no matter what folks suggest, inheritance is *not* the solution you want. Use composition, and likely your StoreInventory object should hold either an array of Snack or a collection such as an array list of Snack -- `ArrayList<Snack>`.

e.g.,

```
public class StoreInventory {
   private List<Snack> snackList = new ArrayList<Snack>();
   // ... etc...

  public void addSnack(Snack snack) {
     snackList.add(snack);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two standard ways:

- Aggregation: You have a `StoreInventory` data member within your class definition and use it. E.g.:

  ```
  class Snacks {
      private StoreInventory inventory;

      Snacks() {
          this.inventory = new StoreInventory();
      }
  }
  ```
- Inheritance: You derive from `StoreInventory`, e.g.:

  ```
  class Snacks extends StoreInventory {

      Snacks() {
          super(); // <== Initialize the base class
      }
  }
  ```

  Note that the call to `super();` doesn't have to be explicit if there are no arguments; if you leave it out, the compiler will add it for you. But if `StoreInventory` needs construction arguments, that's how you would supply them.

Now you have the terminology, you shouldn't have much trouble finding tutorials for those two concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either inheritance

```
class Snacks extends StoreInventory
```

or composition (most likely this one in your case):

```
class Snacks {
    private final StoreInventory storeInventory = new StoreInventory();
}
```

Although without more information, it's hard to say which would be better, but those are basically your two choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can either `extend` the `StoreInventory` class or include it as a field in the new class.

These techniques are called inheritance and composition respectively.

See this: http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/CompoInherit1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can either

- subclass it e.g. `class MyClass extends StoreInventory`
- or a better option would be use delegation e.g.

  ```
  private final StoreInventory inventory = ....
  ```